# MYSQL Query: show only the post from these $users only

Tags: mysql

I have this database [Database Image](http://dagpin.com/MixFiles/untitled.PNG) and an array of user id

```
<?php
$users = array('0000000002','0000000003');

// I want to show only the post from these $users only..

// I came up with this query..

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM it_posts WHERE postOwner = '0000000002' OR postOwner = '0000000003'"); 
// but it will not display each post from the $users

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) or other similar fetching functions. Your code should look like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM it_posts WHERE postOwner = '0000000002' OR postOwner = '0000000003'"); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo $row['field_name'];
}
```

To get it even *shorter*, use the `IN` clause:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM it_posts WHERE postOwner IN ('0000000002', '000000003'");
```

Comment: I really don't like `mysql_fetch_array`, I'd rather recommend `mysql_fetch_assoc`, because it's more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query` is not intented to display everything. It just generrates a data structure containing all the retrieved items from the database.

Have a look over here:

http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlselect.php

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: It can't display everything, I would tend to avoid it, as you need to know the order that the columns are returned, so you can parse the result correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the schema for table it_posts there is no way to help.

Try doing this in the mysql console and also do `select * from it_posts` and see what you get.

You may find that there are no posts with that user id. It may be that

Also, your column name needs to match what is in the database.